# Max Priority Fee and Max Gas Fee difference and definition

Tags: gas, fees, eip-1559

What is the definition of max priority fee and max gas fee in EIP-1559 enabled Ethereum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is a `Base Fee` which is the minimum fee a transaction must pay to be a valid transaction. The Base Fee changes per block, depending on how full the previous block is.  The Base Fee is burned so the block producer (miner/validator) does not receive any of it.

The `Priority Fee` is what a transaction would pay a block producer when the transaction is included in a block.  The `Max Priority Fee` is a maximum because the block producer may be paid less.  One way this can happen is by specifying a `Max Gas Fee` (a.k.a. Max Fee Per Gas), which is the total fee a transaction is willing to pay.

For example, if a transaction specifies `Max Gas Fee = 9` and `Max Priority Fee = 3`, if `Base Fee = 8`, then `1` would be paid to the block producer (Max Gas Fee - Base Fee), and `8` would be burned (Base Fee).  Such a transaction is only valid in a block whose Base Fee reaches 9 or less.

All the fees are per unit of gas, as [EIP-1559](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md) specifies: `base_fee_per_gas`, `max_priority_fee_per_gas`, `max_fee_per_gas`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147704/discussion-on-answer-by-eth-max-priority-fee-and-max-gas-fee-difference-and-defi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is from blocknative's article on EIP1559 gas fees.

> The Base Fee, which is determined by the network itself. And is
> subsequently burned. A Max Priority Fee, which is optional, determined
> by the user, and is paid directly to miners. The Max Fee Per Gas,
> which is the absolute maximum you are willing to pay per unit of gas
> to get your transaction included in a block. For brevity and clarity,
> we will refer to this as the Max Fee.

You can read more in the link to the full article below

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees%3fhs_amp=true