# What is 'gas' when sending a transaction in web3.js? Is it in gwei? How can I set the gas price of a transaction in gwei?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas

There are so many gas paramaters in web3.js. How can I send a transaction with a custom gas fee in gwei?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main parameters in EIP-1559 are `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas`. Explaining gas and EIP-1559 is not in scope for this question but for example see
[Max Priority Fee and Max Gas Fee difference and definition](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/130963/max-priority-fee-and-max-gas-fee-difference-and-definition/)

In web3.js `sendTransaction` you would specify `type: 0x2` (an EIP-1559 transaction).

The base unit in the Ethereum protocol is `wei` (not Ether or gwei), so units in web3.js will need the correct number of zeros. Use [`web3.utils.toWei(number [, unit])`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-utils.html#towei) to help you.

For example, `web3.utils.toWei('1.5', 'gwei')`.

Here is a [web3.js v1.8 test for `sendTransaction`:](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/v1.8.0/test/e2e.method.send.js#L42-L56)

```
        var receipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            to: accounts[1],
            from: accounts[0],
            nonce: nonceVal,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
            gas: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
            maxFeePerGas: '0x59682F00', // 1.5 Gwei
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x1DCD6500', // .5 Gwei
            type: '0x2'
        })
```

The permalink of the last 3 lines
https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/59b657b8c02af05575dc2d0ed321fa7d3aa8eaf6/test/e2e.method.send.js#L53-L55 shows:

```
            maxFeePerGas: '0x59682F00', // 1.5 Gwei
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x1DCD6500', // .5 Gwei
            type: '0x2'
```

The test uses hardcoded hex values; you'll probably want to use `web3.utils.toWei`. It may also be desirable to convert the decimal wei, to hexadecimal using `web3.utils.toHex`.